# How to find the effort required to lift a hinged platform?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering

I have an aluminum platform that weighs 200#, it is hinged on the long side.  I need to be able to fold it up into the vertical position when it's not needed.  Before I get crazy with nitrogen charged springs. I'd like to figure out the actual effort to lift the 120" x 48" from the horizontal position. I would be lifting the at edge of 120" side of the platform. I've tried for ten minutes to attach picture and I can't figure out how to insert one!

Comment: Are you familiar with free body diagrams, and how to sum the forces and moments?  Regardless, you at least know the force required cannot be $more$ than the object's weight, so if you plan for 200+ lb, it will be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You can buy scissor mechanisms or actuators set to lift or rotate the platform.

As a rough estimate if you have an actuator connected to the platform say 12 inches from the hinge it needs to lift
$$\Sigma M_{hinge}=0,\quad 24*200lbs/12=400lbs$$

Actuators have a variety of brackets and attachments that one needs  to consider when ordering.